# Unable to get private key for Blockchain wallet

Tags: transactions, blockchain, blockchain.info, wallet-recovery

I am new to BTC and I have a question: How to get private key from Blockchain wallet for a "Watch only" address? I have been trying for days with no positive results. Thanks.

Comment: The derivation of a private key from its public key is impossible. A watch-only wallet is explicitly non-spending and cannot be used to spend Bitcoins.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have that private key already. You cannot derive it from the public address. A watch-only address is an imported address.

If you've imported it from a paper wallet, check for the private key that should be printed on the same paper. You can scan the private key and upgrade the watch-only address to one that you can spend from as well.

If you imported some address you do not have the private key of, it will remain a watch-only address for you forever.

Answer (score 0):

How did you add your address to blockchain.info?
Did you use a paper wallet Qrcode to import your address? In this case, you supposed to write your private key and if you haven't you've lost it.

As I remember if you just used blockchai.info to have a wallet, blockchain.info won't give you any private key.